# Как корректно отлавливать завершение потоков std::thread?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Конструкция вида `if( my_thread.joinable()) my_thread.join();` нередко вызывает исключение если деструктор потока был вызван между проверкой на `joinable()` и командой `join()`. Такое поведение программы недопустимо.

Как правильно сигнализировать о завершении работы потока `std::thread`, чтобы не было исключений?

[UPDATE]

Вопрос возник в результате следующей ситуации:

```
class streamer{
    // members...

    std::atomic<bool> run;
    std::thread encoder_thread;
    void stream();

public:
    void Stop();
    // ...
};

void streamer::stream(){
    // init...
    run = true;
    while(run){
        // encode-and-send loop ...
    }
    if( buffer ) vpx_img_free(buffer);
    printf("Buffer cleared\n"); // Printed
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs_framestack);
    framestack.clear();
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs_framestack);
    printf("Framestack cleared\n"); // Printed
}

bool streamer::Start(/* params */){
    // initialization...
    encoder_thread = std::thread(&streamer::stream,this);
}

void streamer::Stop(){
    if( run ){
        run = false;
        printf("Waiting for encoder\n"); // Printed
        if( encoder_thread.joinable()) encoder_thread.join();

        printf("Thread closed\n"); // Can't see this in console!

        vpx_codec_destroy(&ctx);
    }
}
```

При вызове `Stop()` извне в консоль выводит:

Waiting for encoder
Buffer cleared
Framestack cleared

А вот сообщения "Thread closed" нет, хотя вывод "Framestack cleared" это последняя инструкция в функции потока, то есть не в функции дело.

В чём же??

Comment: `если деструктор потока был вызван между проверкой` - Имеется ввиду `если поток завершился` или именно вызван деструктор переменной типа  std::thread ?

Comment: @Chorkov, переменная вряд ли уничтожается, так как является членом класса, который удаляется только по закрытию программы. Так что речь о завершении работы функции, запущенной в потоке. Причём иногда завершение проходит нормально, без исключения. В результате отладки выявлено, что именно `join()` вызывает исключение

Comment: join() может выдать исключение только если переменной my_thread небыл назначен никакой поток. Если поток завершен - то join() должен отрабатывать нормально. Ошибка где-то в другом месте. Например, перед join был выполнен `my_thread=...`   `foo(move(my_thread))` или изменение переменной my_thread как-то еще.

Comment: @Chorkov, я дополнил вопрос. Переменная потока нигде не меняется, повторно инициализация не происходит

Comment: Ничего не понятно. При чем здесь потоки вообще? Если вы как-то умудрились вызвать деструктор объекта, то вызывает после этого методы этого объекта уже нельзя. Как образом так получилось, что у вас "вызван деструктор потока"? Просто перестаньте вызывать деструктор потока - и проблема решена.

Comment: Что такое `stream_thread` в вашем коде??? Как он связан c `encoder_thread`?

Comment: @AnT, ну как при чём? Метод класса вызывается в потоке. При завершении крашится на `join()`. Почему, если вся функция отрабатывает? `encoder_thread` естественно, исправил, но в программе всё ок, просто из разных мест копировал )

Comment: ` streamer::Start` не могла быть вызвана повторно?

Comment: @Chorkov, нет. дополнительно проверил - нет

Comment: Добавьте `fflush(stdout);` после `printf("Thread closed\n");` (возможно, сработала буферезация вывода.)  Добавьте вывод `encoder_thread.native_handle()`. (Возможно, где-то расстрелена память.) В приведенном коде видимых ошибок нет.

Comment: @Chorkov, буферизации нет, а `native_handle()` что делает? В общем, если поток не `join()`ить, вылетов нет, и последующие вызовы `Start()` работают корректно. Но отпускать поток в свободное плавание и терять контроль, как-то не правильно... Как-то ещё можно отладить потоки кроме консольных выводов? Может ли это как-то быть связанно с тем, что в функции потока используется создавший этот поток экземпляр класса по указателю?

Comment: Без **минимального воспроизводимого** примера такого поведения вопрос бесполезен.